# Python opencv code freezes after around 30 seconds of running

Tags: python, opencv, arduino

My object detection opencv code runs well for around half a minute, then freezes. When I move the object that it's supposed to be detecting off the camera, the windows showing the frame (and I'm assuming the code aswell) unfreezes until I bring the object back into the camera's view (it immediately freezes again if it recognizes the object).

I have serial communication hooked up from the opencv script to an arduino that controls motors that orient the camera so the object I'm detecting gets moved to the center of the camera POV.

I thought it might be a processing issue so I got rid of the `.erode()` and `.dilate()` commands but it didn't change anything. It seems like the code is freezing either when the color mask is being made or when the contours are being searched for.

Python code

```
import cv2
import numpy
import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial("COM11", 9600) #open serial port

def nothing(x):
    pass

capture=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while capture.isOpened:

    lower_hsv=numpy.array([60, 90, 116]) #hsv values set so that it only sees a certain shade of blue
    upper_hsv=numpy.array([125, 251, 255])

    ret, frame=capture.read()
    blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5,5), 0) #blurs the BGR
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #changes blurred BGR to HSV

    mask=cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hsv, upper_hsv)
    mask=cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask=cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    contours,_=cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if len(contours)>0:
        for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 800:
                continue
            else:
                (x,y), radius=cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
                center=(int(x), int(y))
                radius=int(radius)
                cv2.circle(frame, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                print(center)
                if center[0]<300:
                    ser.write('L'.encode()) #if ball is to the left, rotate the motor to the left
                elif center[0]>340:
                    ser.write('R'.encode()) #if ball is to the right, rotate motor to the right
                elif center[1]<220:
                    ser.write('D'.encode()) #if the ball is below, rotate the motor down
                elif center[1]>260:
                    ser.write('U'.encode())
                else:
                    print('not sending anything')

    result=cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow('original',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
capture.release()
```

Arduino code

```
const int motorA_1 = 9;
const int motorA_2 = 10;
const int motorB_1 = 5;
const int motorB_2 = 6;

char inputData;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  pinMode(motorA_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorA_2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorB_1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorB_2, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available()>0){
    inputData=Serial.read();
    if (inputData == 'R'){
      digitalWrite(motorA_1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorA_2,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }  
    else if(inputData=='L'){
      digitalWrite(motorA_1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorA_2,HIGH);
      delay(10);
    }
    else if(inputData=='U'){
      digitalWrite(motorB_1,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motorB_2,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }
    else if(inputData=='D'){
      digitalWrite(motorB_1,LOW);
      digitalWrite(motorB_2,HIGH);  
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  else{
    doNothing();
  }
}

void doNothing(){
  Serial.println("doing nothing");
  digitalWrite(motorA_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorA_2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorB_1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorB_2, LOW);
  delay(20);
```

I want the script to run until I terminate it by pressing 'esc', but it crashes if I run it for more than 30 seconds.

Comment: Try displaying the number of contours you are getting, i.e. could there be a large number of them?  When you say freeze, I assume your output window is not being updated.

Comment: Start by finding the exact spot where it freezes. You can do that by running a debugger or adding print after each instruction

Comment: In opencv 3.x or higher you should use 
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
Function return three variables.